# Can't access my data on old HDD, the USB adapter shows only Windows and program files

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, sata, ide, ata

I have an old 2.5 ATA/IDE HDD, since my PC had problems with the motherboard I bought a ATA/IDE USB adapter.

It does connect to the PC from the adapter, but I can only access the Windows installation and the Program Files folders.

The Documents and settings folder is empty. I enabled the "view hidden files option" to see if there was more but I found nothing.

What can I do to see the all the data that is in my hard drive?

Comment: what windows version was that? can it be in onedrive/documents etc.?

Comment: There hasn't been a "Documents and Settings" folder in a Windows install since Windows XP, a long, long time ago. Is that what you have?

Answer (score 1):

Each **user** has special folders, such as *Contacts*, *Documents* and *Videos*. Most likely, you're looking in the *Default* user's folders, i.e., those folders, created empty, when Windows is installed. Look in your own folders.

[image: Windows Users folders]

Anther possibility is that the data actually was stored in another place. The data could be **in another partition** on that drive, or **on another HDD or SSD**, or it might be **in the cloud**, such as in OneDrive. One can set the location of those "special" folders. Use a tool such as Nirsoft's [SpecialFoldersView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/special_folders_view.html) to see where those folders *currently* are located -- though it will not tell you where they were when the external drive was a *boot* drive.